# What's the simplest way to distribute an RSA public key with software?

Tags: c#, rsa, digital-signature, public-key-encryption, public-key

I'm working on some software that exchanges XML documents with a server. The server signs the XML using XMLDSIG and the client should verify the signature before trusting the XML. I'm using `RSACryptoServiceProvider` to do this. The XML is signed, but not encrypted.

I'm following the basic procedure explained in:
[How to Sign XML Documents with Digital Signatures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229745(v=vs.110).aspx)
[How to Verify the Digital Signatures of XML Documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229950(v=vs.110).aspx)

This requires that the client software has the public key available. I want the distribution of the client software to be as simple as possible and I don't want the client to have to deal with certificates. The pair of documents referenced above conveniently skirt around the subject of distributing the public key, simply stating that the user "needs to have the same key". I don't particularly want the end user to even be aware that they have a public key, so asking them to mess around with certificates is out of the question. Since the public key is public, what I would like to do is somehow embed it within the client software. As I see it, my options are:

- Install the public key during the setup process
- Somehow embed the public key into the software itself, possibly within the App.config file

Is this feasible in practice? What is the simplest way of achieving this that doesn't require any user interaction or awareness?

Comment: Are you using a self-signed certificate or is it signed by some authority whose certificate can be assumed to be installed on the user's computer?

Comment: Don't see the issue here, you can store a certificate in software without bothering the end user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to distribute the certificate. One of common approaches is to include the certificate in the signed document, in the `KeyInfo/X509Data` node.

The validation can use the embedded certificate easily and the only required infrastructure element at the client side is the certificate thumbprint and subject name. In other words, client validates the document using included certificate and then easily checks the certificate agaist the subject name and thumbprint. In case of a match, there is the assumption that a correct certificate has been provided.

Read more about technical details in one of my blog entries (this is a 3 part tutorial so you can also take a look at all other entries). Anyway, no importing certificates and no including certificates with your software, rather you have two string configuration parameters.

The embedded certificate inside the XmlDsigned document has a const size and usually the overhead is neglectable.

http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2012/12/interoperable-xml-digital-signatures-c.html

http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2012/12/interoperable-xml-digital-signatures-c_20.html

Comment: @svick: no problem, sometimes could hit a weak nail everyone misses. There are no inappropriate questions.

Comment: @WiktorZychla +1 Thank you, this looks promising and I will study your tutorial (actually I already looked at part 1). So I have the XMLDSIG already but I am missing the X509Data containing the public key. Hopefully your articles will explain how to get that.

Comment: What would be the implications of not having the subject name and thumbprint available in the client? Since the public key is included in the signed XML, I can validate authenticity of the document with no further information, right? So what additional protection does the subject name and thumbprint offer?

Comment: @TimLong: svick's concern is just about that. Without the thumbprint you validate that the document is correctly signed with **a** certificate. Anyone can just create a certificate, use it to sign documents and you would not notice. Thumbprint validation (comparing to a known one) is just to prevent that.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Ah I see, makes sense. So verification only proves that the document was not altered, not who it came from. Fair enough. In your blog posts, you use a helper class to get the X%09Data from a certificate. I don't have a certificate (at least, the RSA provider is creating it for me behind the scenes and putting it in a named container). This is nice and simple as I do not have to ever touch a certificate. But in that situation, how do I get the KeyInfoX509Data ? (sorry if these are stupid questions, I'm new at this)

Comment: The certificate is needed only when you **sign**, not when you validate. Certificates can be created easily, programmatically or with a tool.

Comment: I have a proof of concept working based on the sample code in your blog series. I can validate the thumbprint OK. I'm having a bit of trouble with the subject name though. Is there a limitation on what can be used as a subject name? I am trying to use a GUID.

Comment: @TimLong: not really, subject name is a composite name that consists of several other parts (common name, organisation name etc.) Why would that matter?

Answer (score 2):

Am not sure what problem you're facing without seeing your code but, could [this answer from Ji Zhou](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/67b50472-b23f-4191-b8f4-e4a696fca5e4/how-to-use-a-public-key-with-rsacryptoserviceprovider-class?forum=csharplanguage) help?

```
public static void Main()
 {
     try
     {        //initialze the byte arrays to the public key information.
         byte[] PublicKey = {214,46,220,83,160,73,40,39,201,155,19,202,3,11,191,178,56,
                            74,90,36,248,103,18,144,170,163,145,87,54,61,34,220,222,
                            207,137,149,173,14,92,120,206,222,158,28,40,24,30,16,175,
                            108,128,35,230,118,40,121,113,125,216,130,11,24,90,48,194,
                            240,105,44,76,34,57,249,228,125,80,38,9,136,29,117,207,139,
                            168,181,85,137,126,10,126,242,120,247,121,8,100,12,201,171,
                            38,226,193,180,190,117,177,87,143,242,213,11,44,180,113,93,
                            106,99,179,68,175,211,164,116,64,148,226,254,172,147};

        //Values to store encrypted symmetric keys.
         byte[] EncryptedSymmetricKey;
         byte[] EncryptedSymmetricIV;

        //Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider.
         RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

        //Get an instance of RSAParameters from ExportParameters function.
         RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo = RSA.ExportParameters(false);

        //Set RSAKeyInfo to the public key values. 
         RSAKeyInfo.Modulus = PublicKey;
         //Import key parameters into RSA.
         RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);

        //Create a new instance of the RijndaelManaged class.
         RijndaelManaged RM = new RijndaelManaged();

        //Encrypt the symmetric key and IV.
         EncryptedSymmetricKey = RSA.Encrypt(RM.Key, false);
         EncryptedSymmetricIV = RSA.Encrypt(RM.IV, false);

        Console.WriteLine("RijndaelManaged Key and IV have been encrypted with RSACryptoServiceProvider.");
     }
     catch (CryptographicException e)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
     }
 }
```

Comment: I don't understand how does this answer the question.

Comment: @svick - 1) i did say i couldn't quite understand what issue the OP was having with this and 2) given 1), the OP asks for a way to not have the public key dealt by the cliente but rather quote `•Somehow embed the public key into the software itself, possibly within the App.config file`. My answer has the public key as byte array in code

Comment: The problem being solved is: to verify a signed XML document signed using XMLDSIG standard without the client having to install any certificates or configure anything. +1 for a useful answer though.